# How to integrate AWS paramater store to encrypt token / API keys with Python code on EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-parameter-store

I am creating a telegram bot. This requires me to include a token in my Python code to access my bot. I am pretty sure that I should keep it in AWS parameter store so that it is more secure. I am unsure how to do so with the following questions:

- Which python package & function should I use so that I can reference the stored token in AWS parameter store?
- Correct me if I'm wrong, but I also need to give my EC2 instance the IAM role to access my AWS parameter store, right?
- Can I confirm that I shouldn't use AWS secrets manager since I don't intend to rotate this fixed token for my bot?

P.S. Sorry if these are very basic questions. I wasn't sure where to find resources to specifically integrate AWS parameter store with Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which python package & function should I use so that I can reference the stored token in AWS parameter store?

You can use boto3's [get_parameter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter) function.

> I also need to give my EC2 instance the IAM role to access my AWS parameter store, right?

Yes.

> Can I confirm that I shouldn't use AWS secrets manager since I don't intend to rotate this fixed token for my bot?

SSM Paramter Store is free, unlike AWS secrets manager. But you could still use it if you like.